# Lifecycle rule on S3 bucket not deleting old backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this lifecycle rule applied on my S3 bucket on aws to keep the latest 10 backups and delete the others.

This has been active for many months, but it's not working. The backups are coming weekly, but the old objects are not being deleted, the bucket currently has 38 objects.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to achieve this?

[image: lifecycle rules]
[image: lifecycle rule configuration]

Comment: Are you sure that these weekly backup objects all have the same S3 key, so there are more than 10 versions of the same-named object?

Comment: What do you mean having the same S3 key? They all show up under Amazon S3 > Buckets > so-gitlab-backup, different filenames

Comment: This lifecycle rule relates to [versioned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html) objects. Versioning in Amazon S3 is a way of retaining multiple versions of an object in the same bucket. So, for example, you might have prod.zip at v1, v2, v3 where v3 is the latest (i.e. current) version and v1 and v2 are the prior versions (of the object). If you don't know what versioning is then these are likely not versioned objects and that explains why nothing is being expired by your lifecycle rule.

Comment: See [Using S3 Versioning with S3 Lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/Versioning.html#versioning-lifecycle).